# Getting the Pre-mature End of file error

Tags: java, xslt

This is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.abc.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:key name="effectLookup"
       match="/InputAnimationConfigurationSchema/ConfigurationEffects/*" 
       use="@Id" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <body>
    <h2></h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Widget</th>
        <th>Trigger</th>
        <th>effects</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "/InputAnimationConfigurationSchema/ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap" />
    </table>
  </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ConfigurationMap">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(ConfigurationEffects)">
    <xsl:call-template name="EmptyConfiguration">
      <xsl:with-param name="widgetType" select="Widget/@Type" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ConfigurationEffects/Effect" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Effect">
 <tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../Widget/@Type"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../Trigger/@Type"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('effectLookup', ./text())/@DisplayName" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="EmptyConfiguration">
<xsl:param name="widgetType" />
<tr>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="$widgetType"/>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my XML:

```
<InputAnimationConfigurationSchema>
<ConfigurationEffects>
<AEffect Id="1" DisplayName="A Effect">
</WipeEffect>
<BEffect Id="2" DisplayName="B Effect">
</FadeEffect>
<CEffect Id="3" DisplayName="C Effect">
</ConfigurationEffects>
<ConfigurationMappings>
<ConfigurationMap>
<Widget Type="All" Include="true"
   NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
<Trigger Type="Show" />
<ConfigurationEffects>
<Effect>1</Effect>
<Effect>2</Effect>
<Effect>3</Effect>
<Effect>9</Effect>
</ConfigurationEffects>
</ConfigurationMap>
<ConfigurationMap>
<Widget Type="All" Include="true" 
  NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
<Trigger Type="Hide" />
<ConfigurationEffects>
<Effect>1</Effect>
<Effect>2</Effect>
<Effect>3</Effect>
<Effect>9</Effect>
</ConfigurationEffects>
</ConfigurationMap>
<ConfigurationMap>
<Widget Type="PIGWidget" Include="false" 
  NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
</ConfigurationMap>
<ConfigurationMap>
<Widget Type="PlaceHolder" Include="false" 
  NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
</ConfigurationMap>
</ConfigurationMappings>
</InputAnimationConfigurationSchema>
```

and this is my java code:

```
package com.abc;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize.Other;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class XmlToHtml 
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String dataXML = args[0];
    String inputXSL = args[1];
    String outputHTML = args[2];

    XmlToHtml xmltoHtml = new XmlToHtml();
        try
        {
          xmltoHtml.transform(dataXML, inputXSL, outputHTML);
        }
        catch(TransformerConfigurationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("TransformerConfigurationException" + e);
        }
        catch(TransformerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("TransformerException" + e);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException" + e);
        }
}

    public void transform(String dataXML , String inputXSL, String outputHTML) 
throws FileNotFoundException,TransformerException,TransformerConfigurationException
{
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslDoc = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
    Source xmlDoc = new StreamSource(dataXML);
    OutputStream htmlDoc = new FileOutputStream(outputHTML);
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
    transformer.transform(xmlDoc, new StreamResult(htmlDoc));
  }
 }
```

When i am execute the XmltoHtml.java i am getting error like [Fatal Error] new_xmltohtml.xsl:1:1: Premature end of file.
ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

As i passed the path as arguments in the eclipse.  Need guidance and help for the same

Comment: " passed the path as arguments in the eclipse" - the _full_ path or just a relative path?  If the latter, are you sure the working directory of your Java process is the one you expect?

Comment: ok, it was working fine now..thanks for your support and help

Answer (score 1):

there is no start tag for

```
</WipeEffect>
```

in your xml ..line number 4
Your xml is not a valid xml.

Comment: Signatures are not allowed. Do not promote other websites as part of your answers. External links are only encouraged if they provide solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal---ok..i will take care for future reference. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

The element types `"AEffect", "BEffect", and "CEffect"` must be terminated by the matching end-tags `"</AEffect>", "</BEffect>" and "</CEffect>"` in your input XML.